# Replace EditText with android.support.v7.widget.CardView tag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have an EditText in my layout file. Once user clicks on this field, I want it to get replaced with the below element tag. How do I do it ?

From:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp" />
```

To:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give id to both views and initially hide CardView by setting visibility to GONE

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In your java class change the visibility of cardview and edittext when user click

```
mEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      mEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      mCardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to embed them in a LinearLayout or something similar and to change the visibility on user click. Hide the EditText and show the CardView.

Answer (score 0):

You should add them both in your layout and by default set CardView visibility to `GONE`.

Then in your class, where you handle user click, set `EditText` visibility to `View.GONE` and `CardView` visibility to `View.VISIBLE`

Answer (score 0):

Implement edittext's `OnClickListener` and inside `onClick()` method hide your edittext and unhide cardview by calling method `edittext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` and `cardview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`